# Declaration merging doesn't work with express 4.17.* Request type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, definitelytyped

I want to add a property to the Request type, so I created a folder @types/express and in this folder I've added file index.d.ts with this content.

```
namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user: number;
  }
}
```

In VSCode the error has gone while I'm referencing to `req.user`, and it even shows that `user` is of type `number`
[screenshot that shows that "user" property on the "Request" object is treated right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtevx.png)

but when I start the server I see the error that says this:

```
/home/myself/web/my-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:434
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts:46:7 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

46   req.user;
         ~~~~

    at createTSError (/home/myself/web/my-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:434:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/myself/web/my-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:438:19)
    at getOutput (/home/myself/web/my-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:578:36)
    at Object.compile (/home/myself/web/my-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:775:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/myself/web/my-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:858:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/myself/web/my-server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:861:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
```

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to fix it.

p.s. I have done the same with `express-session` module and added a `counter` property into the `Session` interface, and it works flawlessly

Answer (score 4):

With [`@types/express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express) installed ([`@types/express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express-session) is sufficient, too), this should work:

**`index.d.ts`**:

```js
declare module '@types/express-serve-static-core' {
  interface Request {
    user?: User
  }
}
```

The important part is that the declaration merging logic for this is part of `@types/express-serve-static-core` (see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts).

Answer (score 2):

After loosing a few brain cells I provide myself with answer.
To fix the issue I had to recreate folder structure that can be found in this issue
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39581

Then I modified tsconfig.json so its typeRoots would look like this

```
 "typeRoots": [
      "src/typings/",
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ]
```

Then, to augment Request type with my custom types I had to use import expression, so in the end the index.d.ts file would have this inside

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user: import("mongoose").Model<import("./../../models/user").User>;
  }
}
```

tsconfig for the guy in the comments

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
               /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
                     /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "build" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "rootDir": "src" /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
                     /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/typings/",
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ] /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,

    /* Advanced Options */
    "resolveJsonModule": true /* Include modules imported with '.json' extension */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig? I just cannot get this working at all

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 I've added it to the post